# BackupManagerService error when enabling mobile data on custom build ics 4.0.4

Tags: android

We are trying to build a custom build of Android ICS (4.0.4 version) for our own hardware board. On this environment, we are currently observing that when we start the GPRS through PPP in the COMMAND LINE, it is connected successfully and we are able to browse the internet also successfully.

But however, when we try to enable the same in "Mobile Networks" menu option of the "Settings" menu in our Android build (through our touch screen), we find that the GPRS connectivity is not starting.

On debugging, we find that the logcat output when we go in for this screen in our custom Android build for the same is as follows (some parts of relevant section):

i am able to get my log messages till AsyncChannel send(msg) in AsyncChannel.java class but after sendmessage not getting into the callback mechanism and onSetUserDataEnabled(enabled)
Is it a permission related issue?

the logcat snippet when i turn on mobile data is:

```
D/ConnectivityService( 2467): setMobileDataEnabled(true)
D/ConnectivityService( 2467): Data enabled: user=false, policy=true
W/BackupManagerService( 2467): dataChanged but no participant pkg='com.android.providers.settings' uid=1001
```

complete locat o/p is [here](http://pastebin.com/dB7fzfpU) 
We would highly be obliged if anyone had faced the same issue before and if so how we can get this resolved. Thanks in advance for your help.

thanks